# How to put/paste the content where cursor is there in content editable div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable, content-editor

I am a newbie on react. I have a content editable div. What I want is Make a button, on button click -> "HEY" word will be added. Let's say my content length is 100, and I have clicked on initial 5 character and giving the space and click my paste button. So the "HEY" content will be append in that position.

My code:

```
renderValue = () => {
 var textNode = document.createTextNode("HEY");
      let p1 = document.getElementById('work').focus();
      p1.appendChild(textNode)
}

render(){
<button onClick={() => this.renderValue()}>Paste</button>
<div id="work" onClick={(e)=>e.stopPropagation()}  
contentEditable 
onInput={this.emitChange}
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.html}}
>
</div>
}
```

I have tried to append the text but not getting luck.

Anny help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.execCommand()` with `insertText` command. Like

```js
document.execCommand("insertText", false, "HEY!!")
```

Comment: execCommand() is deprecated.  It shouldn't be used anymore.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand